# socket.io webpack build on production server results error

Tags: socket.io

When I include socket.io as a dependency my `webpack` build fails only on the production server:

```
    events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I confirmed it is `socket.io` causing the error. Here is the version in my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
  }
```

Everything works fine on my development box....

I am a bit lost on debugging the error. `node` version is `8.9.4` for production and `8.9.1` for development.

Ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

dang, I had to get rid of `package-lock.json` and everything worked